# Load Text File as a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, text-files

I have a text-file which is a huge set of data(around 9 GB). I have arranged the file as 244 X 3089987 with data delimited with tabs. I would like to load this text-file in Matlab as a matrix. Here is what I have tried and I have been unsuccessful (My Matlab gets hung).

```
fread = fopen('merge.txt','r');

formatString = repmat('%f',244,3089987);

C = textscan(fread,formatString);
```

Am I doing something wrong or is my approach wrong? If this is easily possible in Python, could someone please suggest accordingly.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What was unsuccessful? Did you encounter a memory error or was no data read in at all? As a start, `formatSpec` is more easily defined per line (with a line ending `\r\n`), not for the entire file.

Comment: Well, My matlab gets hung and I had to force exit all the time. I waited for around 2 hrs for some error but it just gets hung all the time.

Comment: That might be important information to include with your question, don't you think?

Comment: Yes, could you please help me? What could I do here?

Comment: It's entirely dependent on how you intend to use the data. Do you need to load all of it at once or can you process the data in chunks? If you need to load all of it, you need to have enough memory.

Comment: Well I need to solve the A\B (linear equation). It would be nice to have the entire thing as A and work. Or how could I do it in chunks (say 10 X 3089987 ). Could you please suggest?

Comment: Do you have 3089987 lines or columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the documentation for [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) you will see that you can define an input argument `N` so that:

> textscan reads file data using the formatSpec N times, where N is a
>   positive integer. To read additional data from the file after N
>   cycles, call textscan again using the original fileID. If you resume a
>   text scan of a file by calling textscan with the same file identifier
>   (fileID), then textscan automatically resumes reading at the point
>   where it terminated the last read.

You can also pass a blank `formatSpec` to `textscan` in order to read in an arbitrary number of columns. This is how [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html), a wrapper for `textscan` operates.

For example:

```
fID = fopen('test.txt');
chunksize = 10; % Number of lines to read for each iteration
while ~feof(fID) % Iterate until we reach the end of the file
    datachunk = textscan(fID, '', chunksize, 'Delimiter', '\t', 'CollectOutput', true);
    datachunk = datachunk{1}; % Pull data out of cell array. Can take time for large arrays
    % Do calculations
end
fclose(fID);
```

This will read in 10 line chunks until you reach the end of the file.

If you have enough RAM to store the data (a `244 x 3089987` array of `double` is just over 6 gigs) then you can do:

```
mydata = textscan(fID, '', 'Delimiter', '\t', 'CollectOutput', true);
mydata = mydata{1}; % Pull data out of cell array. Can take time for large arrays
```

Answer (score 1):

try:
`A = importdata('merge.txt', '\t');`

http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html

and if the rows are not delimited by `'\n'`:
`[C, remaining] = vec2mat(A, 244)`

http://es.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html

Comment: What do I do if the rows are delimited by '\n' ?

Comment: @JesuKiranSpurgen, use only `A = importdata('merge.txt', '\t');`

Answer (score 1):

Another option in recent MATLAB releases is to use `datastore`. This has the advantage of being designed to allow you to page through the data, rather than read the whole lot at once. It can generally deduce all the formatting stuff.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/read-and-analyze-data-in-a-tabulartextdatastore.html

Comment: The version I am using is Matlab R2012b, I guess it doesn't work on this version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this is even trying to run, when I try something similar textscan throws an error.

If you really want to use textscan you only need the format for each row so you can replace 244 in your code with 1 and it should work. Edit: having read your comment not that in the first element is the number of columns so you should do `formatString = repmat('%f',1, 244);`. Also you can apparently just leave the format as empty (`''`) and it will work.

However, Matlab has several [text import functions](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/text-files.html) of which textscan is rarely the easiest way to do something.

In this case I would probably use [dlmread](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html), which does any delimitated numerical data. You want something like:

```
C=dlmread('merge.txt', '\t');
```

Also as you are trying to load 9GB of data I assume you have enough memory, you'll probably get an out of memory error if you don't but it is something to consider.

Comment: Not particularly. `textscan(fID, '', 'Delimiter', '\t')` is functionally equivalent (because that's what `dlmread` does).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could leave the format empty.